# Add a title to the top of multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add a title at the top of a plot of 6 combined `ggplots`?
I have currently used this code to add a title which places it in the centres of my 6 plots, how would I move it to the top?

Each `res_plot` here is just a standard `ggplot`:

```
all_plots = res_plot1 + res_plot2 + res_plot3 + res_plot4 + res_plot5
  
all_plots + ggtitle("Residual Plots")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming from your syntax that you are using the `patchwork` package. In that case you can use `plot_annotation`:

```r
library(patchwork)

res_plot1 <- res_plot2 <- res_plot3 <- res_plot4 <- res_plot5 <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

 all_plots <- res_plot1 + res_plot2 + res_plot3 + res_plot4 + res_plot5
 
 all_plots + plot_annotation(title = "Residual Plots")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know the code to move it to be centred?

Comment: @Joe try `plot_annotation(title = "Residual Plots", theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))`